# Can you call a function base on a variable in js?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I have a really long winded switch case statement like this

```
switch(x){
   case "a":
      // call function a
      a():
      break;
   case "b":
      // call function b
      a():
      break;
   case "c":
     // call function c
     c():
     break;
}
```

Can't i simply say

```
// If the x variable is set, call the corresponding function
 If (x){
  x();
}
```

The only reason its not working is because it thinks that im calling the function x(), but i want to use x as a placeholder for other functions. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends where your function is defined. If its defined in global scope, you can say: 
`if (window[x]) window[x]();`

If its part of an object which is in global scope, say:

```
var obj = function() {
  this.x = function() {
      // do something
      };
}
```

then you can call it like:

`window[obj][x]();`

This is to get you started. You should add null checks and whether its really a function or not in your final routine.

If you use jQuery, you can check by saying: `if (jQuery.isFunction(window[x])) window[x]();`

Comment: hmm interesting... and if its not?

Comment: Better to test *x* first. If it's expected to be a native function, then: `if (typeof window[x] == 'function') window[x]();`, if it might be a host method, then `if (window[x]) window[x]();` is all that can be done since host methods don't have to (and are known not to in some browsers) follow the rules for *typeof*.

Comment: @RobG: Yes of course. As I said, it all depends on where it is declared and how.

Comment: interesting... got it to work 120 lines of code to 38 lines. Good stuff!

Comment: Almost -1 for the jQuery comment :-). jQuery's *isFunction* just does a typeof test, so not only is it very inefficient (function call vs operator test), it will fail for host methods in many browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Create a cache of the functions you wish to call:

```
var fnCache = {
  a: function(){},
  b: function(){},
  c: function(){}
};
```

then in your code:

```
  // x is assigned a value somehow
  var x = 'a';

  // ... later ...

  if (typeof fnCache[x] == 'function') {
    fnCache[x]();
  }
```

Assuming that all the functions are native and not host methods (see comment on Mrchief's post).

Comment: Anytime I see the word cache, I've to give a +1 ;). This is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a number of ways, but to give you an example similar to what you want:

```
function foo(x)
{
    x();
}

function bar()
{
    alert('test');
}

foo(bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// If the x variable is set, call the corresponding function
If (x){
   x();
}
```

> but i want to use x as a placeholder for other functions. Is this possible?

No, `x` is a variable in both cases.  `x()` is not a function name, it's a function call, where the `x` is the variable and the `()` is actual call.  Function variables and other variables are both stored in the same global namespace and would overwrite eachother, so you couldn't use two versions of the same name.  You'd have to store it in an object or call it something else.

You could do something like:

```
if (typeof x === 'function'){
   x();
}
```